# JS: Avoiding modifications of ".innerHTML"

Tags: javascript, html

I have some `<div>` in which I all the time add new objects.
These objects are assigned with listeners.

The problem is that when I add these new objects using `.innerHTML`, the previous listeners get lost.

Is it possible to create a JS string which represents an HTML object, and to append it as a child without `.innerHTML += ...` ?

I'll give an example:

```
var line_num = 0;
function addTextLine(line) {
    var lineId = "line_" + line_num;
    var lineHtml = "<p id = '" + lineId + "'>" + line + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("some_div_id").innerHTML += lineHtml;
    document.getElementById(line_id).addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
    line_num += 1;
}
```

The modification of `innerHTML` of `some_dive_id`, removes the event listeners of the old `<p>` objects.

So - is it possible to convert the `<p>` HTML string into an object, and thus to append it to the `some_div_id` without modifying its `.innerHTML` ?

Comment: You can use [DOM APIs like `.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) to add new nodes to the DOM.

Comment: But how can I convert the text `<p>...</p>` into an appendable object?

Comment: Using APIs like `createElement()` and `setAttribute()`.

Comment: Could you please answer with an example?

Comment: One can hardly think of a better reason to not use HTML as strings inserted using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that innerHtml erases then recreates the current DOM node; that's why you lose you event listeners.
you can insert your html with insertAdjacentHtml

```
 document.getElementById("some_div_id").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', lineHtml );
```

the `afterbegin` parameter assure the inserted html will be a child of your current node.

Look for more infos here: [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Create the element and append it

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = line;
p.id = line_id; // or p.setAttribute("id", line_id);
p.addEventListener("click", function(){ });
document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(p);
```

Another option can be to create an element, and set the innerHTML and read the element from there. (First option is better)

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = lineHtml;
//now you can either select the children and append it or append the div.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `element.appendChild().`

Your code is not working because everytime you use `innerHtml += 'Something'` you are removing anything inside that particular element and inserting old content with added string.

Instead you can create element with function and append it to parent element.

Rewriting your code should be:

```
var line_num = 0;
function addTextLine(line) {
  var line = document.createElement('p');
  line.id = "line_" + line_num;
  line.textContent = line;
  line.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
  document.getElementById("some_div_id").appendChild(line);
  line_num += 1;
}
```